# Why & How does this "double" to "14-bit Int" code work?

Tags: floating-point, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am wondering if someone could please explain to my why & how this code works, to convert a double between -1.0, and +1.0, to an 14-bit Integer.

How were the values chosen in data14, and what's going on behind the scenes?

```
double data = 0.5;

if (data < -1.0) {
  data = -1.0;
} else if (data > 1.0) {
  data = 1.0;
}

int data14 = (int)((data+1.0)/2.0*16383 + 0.5);

BYTE upper7 = data14 >> 7;
BYTE lower7 = data14 & 0x7f;
```

Comment: Do you understand what bit shifting and bit masking are?  If not, learn those first, then come back to this.  OK, good now?  It might help to understand this code if you keep in mind that decimal 16383 is hex 0x3FFF, which is binary 11111111111111, ie 14 consecutive bits. It would also help to use your debugger to look at the raw bytes of `data14` for any given value of `data`, do the math to understand why `data14` gets set the way it does (eg, `0.5` -> `12287` aka `0x2FF`), and work out on paper why the bit shifting is done the way it is.

Comment: If it helps: `-1.0` becomes `0` and `1.0` becomes `16383` (`0x3FFF`, ie 14 bits max). The code is translating floating-point values between `-1.0..1.0` to decimal values between `0..16383`.

Comment: Whats the reasoning behind adding 1 to data, multiplying 14 bits (0x3FFF) by two, and then add 0.5?

Comment: It is not multiplying 0x3FF by 2. It is dividing `data` by 2 and then multiplying the result by 0x3FF. The +1.0 and +0.5 is to handle rounding issues, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you can parse the correct order of operations, here is the result of the sequence in term of data interval

```
input data             -> (-inf,inf)
if(...) else if () ... -> [-1 , 1]
data+1                 -> [0 , 2]
/2                     -> [0 , 1]
*16383                 -> [0 , 16383]
+0.5                   -> [0.5 , 16383.5]
int()                  -> [0 , 16383]
```

Note that in term of density of probability, a uniform distribution of data in [-1 , 1] would give a biased distribution in [0 , 16383] - the extreme values 0 and 16383 having twice less probability of occurrence than [1,16382].

Maybe that's wanted, otherwise it would be necessary to multiply by the floating point predecessor of 16384 and avoid adding +0.5.

Comment: I think a better alternative to address biasing against the endpoints would be to delay clamping until *after* addition of `0.5`, as rounding is actually desirable in this conversion.